# Convert shift right (Java's >>) to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to konvert java's code to Kotlin:

```
private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
}
```

and I get:

```
private fun appendHex(sb: StringBuffer, b: Byte) {
    sb.append(hex.toCharArray()[b shr 4 and 0x0f]).append(hex.toCharArray()[b and 0x0f])
}
```

But Kotlin's standard `shr` expects Int as a first argument (not `Byte`). The same problem with `and` operator.

How to convert it to Kotlin?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bitwise operations like `and`, `or`, and `shl` are only defined for `Int` and `Long` in Kotlin. (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html)

Just create [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) that take `Byte` values.

```
private fun appendHex(sb: StringBuffer, b: Byte) {
    sb.append(hex.toCharArray()[b shr 4 and 0x0f]).append(hex.toCharArray()[b and 0x0f])
}

infix fun Byte.shl(that: Int): Int = this.toInt().shl(that)
infix fun Int.shl(that: Byte): Int = this.shl(that.toInt()) // Not necessary in this case because no there's (Int shl Byte)
infix fun Byte.shl(that: Byte): Int = this.toInt().shl(that.toInt()) // Not necessary in this case because no there's (Byte shl Byte)

infix fun Byte.and(that: Int): Int = this.toInt().and(that)
infix fun Int.and(that: Byte): Int = this.and(that.toInt()) // Not necessary in this case because no there's (Int and Byte)
infix fun Byte.and(that: Byte): Int = this.toInt().and(that.toInt()) // Not necessary in this case because no there's (Byte and Byte)
```

I used `infix` to use the operations like `1 shl 2` (as opposed to `1.shl(2)`). (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html)

---

Or simply, just add `.toInt()` to every expressions that use `shl` or `and`.

```
private fun appendHex(sb: StringBuffer, b: Byte) {
    sb.append(hex.toCharArray()[b.toInt() shr 4 and 0x0f]).append(hex.toCharArray()[b.toInt() and 0x0f])
}
```

---

Caution: In Java, `<<` has higher operator precedence than `&`. In Kotlin, `shl` and `and` have the same operator precedence because they are both infix *functions*.